# Alias class method as global function

Tags: php, methods, alias

Is it possible to alias a class method as a global function?

I have a class that acts as a wrapper around the gettext functions in PHP. I have a function called `_t()` that deals with translations.

I would like to be able to call it as `_t()` from anywhere in my code without having to do it via an instantiated object (`$translate::_t()`) as that seems quite unwieldy.

I thought about using namespaces to give the object an alias:

```
Use translations\TranslationClass as T
```

Although this is a better improvement: `T::_t()`. it is still not as need as just having to do `_t()`.

Are there anyways to alias `T::_t()` as just `_t()` across the whole application?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can either create a wrapper function or use create_function().

```
function _t() {
    call_user_func_array(array('TranslationClass', '_t'), func_get_arts());
}
```

Or you can create a function on the fly:

```
$t = create_function('$string', 'return TranslationClass::_t($string);');

// Which would be used as:
print $t('Hello, World');
```

Comment: Interesting. I will look into this and get back in a day or so :)

Comment: 2nd approach is tricky. We have dollar sign prefix which usually considered as variable and after we have parentheses to call variable as a function. I think that will bring a lot of mess, confusions and maintenance problems

Comment: Yes and no - it depends on how you look at it. I see variables as pointers to all sorts of data types - including functions. Consider the callable array: $x = [$objectRef, 'objectMethod']; - calling $x() will call $objectRef->objectMethod();. This is a perfectly valid construct. Most languages support the concept of function pointers.

Answer (score 0):

You can use eval() function to convert methods as global functions.

```
function to_procedural($classname, $method, $alias)
{
  if (! function_exists($alias))
  {
   $com  = $command = "function ".$alias."() { ";
   $com .= "\$args = func_get_args(); ";
   $com .= "return call_user_func_array(array(\"".$classname."\", \"".$method."\"), \$args); }";
   @eval($command);
  }
  return function_exists($alias);
}
```

This example works well with static methods.

Comment: How's the performance doing it this one? Will there be any huge performance hits using eval()?